# Holding and moving element (window)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a little problem and I don't know why code does not work.
I have element on site (window) which I want to resize (clicking on corner and pulling).

```
@Test
public void ResizeWindow()
{
    driver.get(URL); 
    WebElement resizeableWindow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='resizable']/div[3]"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(resizeableWindow);
    actions.clickAndHold(resizeableWindow);
    actions.moveByOffset(50,50);
}
```

But this piece of code does not want to resize window (code does not have problem with finding element). Any tips? Or hint on what should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `perform()` as last command to execute the previous commands

```
actions.perform();
```

The methods from `Actions` class return `this`, so you can chain them

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions
    .moveToElement(resizeableWindow)
    .clickAndHold(resizeableWindow)
    .moveByOffset(50,50)
    .perform();
```